# Please explain Webpack LimitChunkCountPlugin, MinChunkSizePlugin, and AggressiveMergingPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm finding the option descriptions for Webpack's `LimitChunkCountPlugin`, `MinChunkSizePlugin`, and `AggressiveMergingPlugin` to be a bit confusing. Some are self-explanatory but others are very vague.

In LimitChunkCountPlugin I'm presented with 3 options:

> `options.maxChunks` (number) max number of chunks
>
> `options.chunkOverhead` (number) an additional overhead for each chunk in bytes (default 10000, to reflect request delay)
>
> `options.entryChunkMultiplicator` (number) a multiplicator for entry chunks (default 10, entry chunks are merged 10 times less likely)

- So `maxChunks` is pretty self-explanatory
- I have no idea what `chunkOverhead` is as it sounds like it adds 10,000 empty bytes to the chunk to reflect a `delay` ??? Which makes no sense
- `entryChunkMultiplicator` is not *as* vague but still pretty vague. I'm guessing is some abstract number where the higher it is the less likely the entry chunk (Theres only 1 entry chunk in my case) will be merged into another chunk

---

In MinChunkSizePlugin I'm presented with one option

> Merge small chunks that are lower than this min size (in chars). Size is approximated.
>
> `options.minChunkSize` (number) chunks smaller than this number will be merged

So how big is a char, an ascii char is 1-byte but a utf-8 and utf-16 can be up to 2 or more bytes (If I'm correct). I'm guessing we're going with 1-char to 1-byte in which case 1024 for example would be 1kb. Also What values do other people use?

---

For the AggressiveMergingPlugin

> `options.minSizeReduce` A factor which defines the minimal required
>   size reduction for chunk merging. Defaults to 1.5 which means that the
>   total size need to be reduce by 50% for chunk merging.
>
> `options.moveToParents` When set, modules that are not in both merged chunks are moved to all parents of the chunk. Defaults to
>   `false`.
>
> `options.entryChunkMultiplicator` When options.moveToParents is set, moving to an entry chunk is more expensive. Defaults to 10, which
>   means moving to an entry chunk is ten times more expensive than moving
>   to an normal chunk.

- `minSizeReduce` is pretty simple, if the chunk can be shrunk down by 50% or more merge it
- `moveToParents` this is also pretty confusing, its set to false by default which throws up red flags that maybe I shouldn't touch it, but it sounds like it duplicates and moves all un-shared modules to all parents. If so why would anyone use that option.
- `entryChunkMultiplicator` this is pretty abstract and vague, it sounds like, when modules are moved to an entry chunk it becmes 10 times slower to access which can't be right. Why would I want to make it slower?

If anyone can clear this up for me thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Looking at the source, I don't see the `chunkOverhead` option for the `LimitChunkCountPlugin`. What version do you use ?

Comment: @adz5A https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

## [LimitChunkCountPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#limitchunkcountplugin)

While writing your code, you may have already added many code split points to load stuff on demand. After compiling you might notice that some chunks are too small - creating larger HTTP overhead. Luckily, this plugin can post-process your chunks by merging them.

## [MinChunkSizePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#minchunksizeplugin)

Keep chunk size above the specified limit by merging chunks that are smaller than the `minChunkSize`.

## AggressiveMergingPlugin

Is actually [absent](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#optimize) in latest API which you probably use. Maybe [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#mergeduplicatechunksplugin)?